# Recycler view is not showing items

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Recycler view is not showing items. `datasnapshot2` is receiving the right value.

`child("Trips").child(tripID).child("Members")` is geting userIDs

[image]

```
        membersRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.members);
        membersRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        membersRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Trips").child(tripID).child("Members");

        databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        DatabaseReference databaseReference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users")
                                .child(Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot1.getKey()));
                        databaseReference1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2) {
                                UserDataModel userDataModel = dataSnapshot2.getValue(UserDataModel.class);
                                membersArrayList.add(userDataModel);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });

                    }
                    membersAdapter = new UserDataAdapter(membersArrayList);
                    membersRecyclerView.setAdapter(membersAdapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
```

Adapter

```
public class UserDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserDataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<UserDataModel> MemberList;
    private TextView userName, userRating;

    UserDataAdapter(List<UserDataModel> MemberList) {
        this.MemberList = MemberList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.members_list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        UserDataModel userDataModel = MemberList.get(position);
        userName.setText(userDataModel.getUserName());
        userRating.setText(userDataModel.getUserRating());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return MemberList.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            userImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.m_user_image);
            userName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.m_user_name);
            userRating = itemView.findViewById(R.id.m_user_rating);
        }
    }
}
```

UserDataModel

```
public class UserDataModel {
    public String userName, userEmail, contactNumber, gender, dateOfBirth, location, userID, createdDate, createdTime;
    int userRating;

    public UserDataModel() {

    }

    UserDataModel(String userName, String userEmail, String contactNumber, String gender, String dateOfBirth, String location, String userID, String createdDate, String createdTime) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.location = location;
        this.userID = userID;
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
        this.createdTime = createdTime;
    }

    String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    String getUserEmail() {
        return userEmail;
    }

    public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
    }

    String getContactNumber() {
        return contactNumber;
    }

    public void setContactNumber(String contactNumber) {
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
    }

    String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    String getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(String dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    String getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(String createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public String getCreatedTime() {
        return createdTime;
    }

    public void setCreatedTime(String createdTime) {
        this.createdTime = createdTime;
    }

    public int getUserRating() {
        return userRating;
    }

    public void setUserRating(int userRating) {
        this.userRating = userRating;
    }
}
```

xml (some things are deleted)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".TripActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/createdBy"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="110dp">

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/createdBy_user_image"
                        android:layout_width="95dp"
                        android:layout_height="95dp"
                        android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@color/black" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/darkgrey" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/heebo_medium"
                    android:text="Trip Description"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/trip_description"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/heebo_light"
                    android:text="This is the description of trip." />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/heebo_medium"
                    android:text="Members"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/members"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:scrollbars="none" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add a screenshot of the database.

Comment: @HasanBouTaam done

Comment: also add this class `UserDataModel `

Comment: @HasanBouTaam done

Comment: The screen shot doesn't show the full data in `users` node

Comment: Show the code snippet of your Recycler item xml file.

Comment: @HasanBouTaam done

Comment: Let me know that did you confirm that the data arrived from database? Check first that the data arrived from database and if it is not then the problem is in database. If data arrival is confirmed then the problem is in recyclerview. Let me know the specific problem, I will try to solve it then. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in Adapter.

Changed

```
userName.setText(userDataModel.getUserName());
userRating.setText(userDataModel.getUserRating());
```

to

```
userName.setText((String.valueOf(userDataModel.getUserName())));
userRating.setText((String.valueOf(userDataModel.getUserRating())));
```

Answer (score 0):

**I see you add many unused fields in your class `UserDataModel`:**

**Try changing your `UserDataModel`:**

```
public class UserDataModel {

//these must be named exactly like your database, and the exact same number
private String userName;
private String userEmail;
private String userID;
private String contactNumber;
private String gender;
private String dateOfBirth;
private String location;


//constructor

public UserDataModel(String userName,String userEmail,String userID,String contactNumber,String gender,String dateOfBirth,String location){

this.userName = userName;
this.userEmail = userEmail;
this.userID = userID;
this.contactNumber=contactNumber;
this.gender = gender;
this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
this.location = location;

}

//generate also getters and setters........

}
```

**One more thing you must do:**

**Do you see these lines of code:**

```
membersAdapter = new UserDataAdapter(membersArrayList);
membersRecyclerView.setAdapter(membersAdapter);
```

**Add them directly under these lines:**

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2) {
UserDataModel userDataModel = dataSnapshot2.getValue(UserDataModel.class);
membersArrayList.add(userDataModel);

//here......

membersAdapter = new UserDataAdapter(membersArrayList);
membersRecyclerView.setAdapter(membersAdapter);
.....
.....
.....
```

**Update2:**

```
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/members"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                ...............
```

Comment: I have to use those unused fields in another places.

Comment: I know that they must match the database.

Comment: did you try to do so?

Comment: Yup. I have done this type of stuff on other places too. But there it didn't had any problem.

Comment: If you want to use the unused fields make another class, and use them, but for firebase keep the fields the same.